# what is the most optimized way of applying conditions over HTTP response's errorCode

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, optimization

I have an ajax call that adds a property errorCode to the response whenever there is an error.The value in the property errorCode is determined with various use cases.There are 10 codes that the call can return i.e 5010,5020,5030 .... 600.

We have two divs in the page

```
 ...rest of the page    
 <div id="unsupported">
 <p>equipment is unsupported</p>
 </div>
 <div id="notFound">
 <p>equipment could not be found</p>
 </div>
 ...rest of the page
```

Now i want to handle the error in the following way

1-if the errorCode is 5020,5030 or 5090
hide all other divs in the background except the two divs

1(a)-if the errorCode is 5020 or 5030,show only #unsupported div

1(b)-if the errorCode is 5090,show only #notFound div

2-if the errorCode is other than 5020,5030 or 5090
simply show a toast with error message

here is the callback function handling the error of the ajax call

```
function(error) {
  // The normal way of doing it
  if (error.errorCode === 5010 || error.errorCode === 5020 || error.errorCode === 5090) {
    hideBackground();
    if (error.errorCode === 5010 || error.errorCode === 5020) {
      showUnsupported();
    } else if (error.errorCode === 5090) {
      showNotFound();
    }
  } else {
    toast(error.message);
  }
}
```

I know its pretty simple but I was thinking there must be an optimized way of doing it by writing lesser code, using javascript/ES6/ES7 features.Looking for an out of the box idea to shorten the code.

Comment: Shorter/less code does not necessarily mean that the performance, readability and/or maintainability is better. Having that said, you could write something like `[5010, 5020, 5090].includes(error.errorCode)`

Comment: I feel there must be a way to decrease the number of if conditions used.That's what I am looking for.I think that will result in better performance as well.

Comment: When it comes to performance, there's probably no solution that would have a better performance than the code you show. This kind of if conditions are easy to optimize for the compiler, and modern JavaScript engines do a really good job in code optimizations and Just in Time compilations. You should always focus on readability and maintainability.

Comment: In addition to t.niese's input, you can work with a single if branch with its own function. If your error code matches the array, call that function. Add a flag to determine if any of those function got called. If not, toast the message.

Comment: @t.niese That makes sense.Thanks a lot (y)

Comment: What does `toast(error.message)` do? That a part looks not correct out of maintainability.

Comment: @t.niese it displays a customized toast on the top of the window.

Comment: @t.niese the call responds with a custom error message (different for each errorCode) toast displays the message to the screen, If i ever need to change the error message I can do that in the backend and i wont need to change the code at frontend,This is what I thought but I would love to hear your opinion on that.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't change much in your code, if conditions are perfectly fine in this case, but I would remove the `if (error.errorCode === 5010 || error.errorCode === 5020 || error.errorCode === 5090) {`  and move the `hideBackground` so that the code would look like this:

```
function(error) {
  if (error.errorCode === 5010 || error.errorCode === 5020) {
    hideBackground();
    showUnsupported();
  } else if (error.errorCode === 5090) {
    hideBackground();
    showNotFound();
  } else {
    toast(error.message);
  }
}
```

If you write the code like this, the question arises automatically, if `hideBackground` has to be called every time `showUnsupported`/`showNotFound` is called, if this is the case then this might be something that has to be moved into those functions.

Or you write a helper like that:

```
function showError(callback) {
  hideBackground()
  callback()
}

function(error) {
  if (error.errorCode === 5010 || error.errorCode === 5020) {
    showError(showUnsupported)
  } else if (error.errorCode === 5090) {
    showError(showNotFound)
  } else {
    toast(error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, you have suggested to use `.includes` method, yet you do not use it? And that seems not so maintainable IMHO.

Comment: @KarelG i didn't suggest to use `.includes` i just said it can be used.

Comment: @KarelG about the maintainability. It removes the outer `if` so that you only have one `if-ifelse-else` chains that is easier to read and understand. You don't need to maintain the error codes at two places. It is clear that `toast` is a fallback error handler. Using an `[5010, 5020].includes(error.errorCode)` could be done, but that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Yes, but what if the manager or client says that the background does not have to be hidden when `5010` is given, but the other rules remains intact.

Comment: @KarelG then something like `displayErrorAsDialog(buildUnsupportedError, {hideBackground:true})` and `displayErrorAsNotification(buildUnsupportedError, {sticky:true})` ist still a better option, then the outer `if`. Or probably: `displayErrorAsDialog(buildUnsupportedError, {hideBackground:errorsWithBackground.includes(error.errorCode)})`

Answer (score -1):

How about this? In case you need to add a new error handler, you just need to create a function and add it to `errors` object. This is good if several errors are doing the same action (such as `5010` and `5020` which is doing the same). I'm attaching two ways to do it.

```js
const error5010 = () => {
  // hideBackground();
  // showUnsupported();
};

const error5020 = error5010;

const error5090 = () => {
  // hideBackground();
  // showNotFound();
};

const errors = {
  error5010,
  error5020,
  error5090,
};

const otherError = () => {
  console.log('Unknown error...');
};

const errorHandler = code =>
  typeof errors['error' + code] === 'function'
    ? errors['error' + code]()
    : otherError()
    ;

errorHandler(5010);
errorHandler(5090);
errorHandler(2000);
```

If you hate to create 10 functions, you could use this instead.

```js
const apply = (fn, cond) => cond ? fn() : null;

const hideBackground = () => {
  console.log('hideBackground');
};

const showNotFound = () => {
  console.log('showNotFound');
};

const showUnsupported = () => {
  console.log('showUnsupported');
};

function errorHandler(code) {
  apply(hideBackground, [5010, 5020, 5090].includes(code));
  apply(showNotFound, [5010, 5020].includes(code));
  apply(showUnsupported,[5090].includes(code));
}

errorHandler(5010);
```

Comment: Why do you write `const error5010 = () => {` instead of `function error5010() {`?  Your code does not seem to do anything mentioned in the `Now i want to handle the error in the following way` part.

Comment: @t.niese writing `const ... = () => ` is just my habit. I'm demonstrating that we could handle the error in such way. I'm editing it now.

Comment: So, instead of having multiple if/else-if/else branches, you now have multiple functions? The OP has 10 error codes. That means you have to write 10 functions...

Comment: @KarelG I added another way.

Comment: @KarelG how about it?